# Fast gnuplot terminal compatible with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot to make some thousands of frames from raw data, I then make a video with ffmpeg (the easiest way I know to use advanced codecs like x264). The frames are not complicated: just few lines and some dots.

Up to now I have been using the pngcairo terminal to produce the frames, but I noticed that postscript is way faster than pngcairo. Unfortunately ffmpeg doesn't recognize postscript, so I was wondering if you know a fast (but still a good quality -at least antialiased) gnuplot terminal which output can be readed by ffmpeg.

Comment: All imagefiles which are supported by ffmpeg are listed here http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Image-Formats. 
you have to try some formats out to find which one works best for you. I would guess that compressed formats (like JPEG) will take longer to render

Comment: Do you have the old libgd based `png` terminal?  You could try that one and see if it is faster.

Comment: @mgilson Yes, it's much faster, but the output is awful: totally aliased. Quality is still the first requirement :)

Comment: @DarioP -- I definitely prefer pngcairo to png for quality.  I can't imagine it makes that much of a difference for a few points and lines though...